# How to decouple an entity class from a control class

Tags: java, uml

Suppose my entity class implements an interface. How do i let my control class to use that interface so that the control class can instantiate that interface as an object.

Initially i would use my control class to instantiate an instance of the entity class. However, i would like to decouple them with the use of interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) design pattern can help here.

Use an interface that defines a generic entity factory. Once your control class has a factory instance (as an interface), it can invoke its createEntity() method to create specific entity instances.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do this is using a static factory method to create and return the `EntityInterface` references. See this elementary example:

```
EntityInterface entity = EntityFactory.getEntity();
```

With the types defined like this:

```
class EntityFactory {
    public static EntityInterface getEntity() {
        return new Entity();
    }
}

interface EntityInterface {

}

class Entity implements EntityInterface {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use static factory method to accomplish this

**Sample implementation**

```
public class ModelFactory implements ModelInterface{


    public static ModelInterface getNewInstance() {
        return new Model();
    }
}


public interface ModelInterface {

}


public class Model implements ModelInterface{

}
```

now in the controller class

```
 ModelInterface object =  ModelFactory.getNewInstance();
```